# Adding checkbox control in datagrid at first column (vb.net 2003)

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, checkbox

I am assigning a 'ds' dataset to datagrid.In addition to that I want to add new column with check boxes.That new column will be first column of datagrid.

Currently I am using below code,

```
DataGrid1.DataSource = dsResult.Tables("Result")
```

Result table has 4 column....in addtion to that i want to column "Selection" with check boxes

Answer (score 1):

You can add a checkbox inside the itemtemplate like

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkComplete" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

For a basic understanding read this article

[Including a CheckBox Control Inside an ASP.NET DataGrid...](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=51)